# How can I target all inputs except checkboxes with Tailwind (and vice-versa)?

Tags: tailwind-css

We have the following DOM:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="[&_input]:block">
  <input type='input' value='hi'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

What style can we add to the parent div to specify that checkbox inputs should not be block? `[&_input]:not(type['checkbox']):block` is not right...

Answer (score 0):

By adding the "flex" class to the parent div, you can achieve the desired result. The updated code would be:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="[&_input]:block flex">
  <input type='input' value='hi'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I'm looking to express a css selector on the div that targets only the checkbox input--how can I do that?